# Mapstraction Google Geocode call returns error code 610

Tags: google-geocoder, mapstraction

I have this `js` code where I am using the Mapstraction library to show GMap and use it's geocoder service via mapstraction as well.

I have recently started getting `error 610` whenever I try to issue the geocode service call. The `http code is 200` ok however the `json` returned is as follows:

```
_xdc_._8gxa9q7ci && _xdc_._8gxa9q7ci( {
  "Status": {
    "code": 610,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
})
```

Chromium's inspector shows the request string as follows:

```
output:json
oe:utf-8
q:nehru place, , delhi,110048, in
mapclient:jsapi
hl:en
callback:_xdc_._8gxa9q7ci
```

The issue remains even with a newly generated api key! The map loads just fine with the new key as well as the old key!

So if anyone has run into a similar issue with mapstraction then do let me know the workarounds if any.

Another thing that I have noticed is that my old key is 86 characters long whereas my new key is only 39 characters long. Any insights in this direction would be greatly appreciated. I have spent an entire day trying to get it to work again.

Update: I have noticed that with a key length of 86 characters, the request string has key: MYKEY param as well. Whereas with the 39 character long key, it's not there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapstraction seems to require a 86 character api key to work properly with GMap API v2.

The 36 character API key is for v3 I guess.

If I goto the API console, the 86 character keys generated for my domains isn't shown there. However, the link to generate the 86 character api key is a bit hard to get.

Once generated, my calls to GMap's Geocoder via Mapstraction are working fine now.

Here's the link to generate the v2 API key
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Remember to scroll to the bottom of the page to fill in the correct url.

As for Mapstraction, I think the latest version should be able to use the new 36 character API key!